# Make a program ignore ".bashrc"

Tags: intel, bashrc, matlab

Sorry if it is an extremely stupid noob question, but I am not an expert and I cannot find any adequate response on this or other forums.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 x64 and I'm working with Intel Compilers. In order to keep my system and the compilation of my software consistent I've set my .bashrc to set the Intel compilers as default.

```
source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018.2.046/bin/psxevars.sh
export CC='/opt/intel/bin/icc'
export CXX='/opt/intel/bin/icpc'
export FC='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
export F77='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
export CFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export CXXFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export FCFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
```

Now, if I do this I cannot start MATLAB R2017b. Every time I start it it clashes with the Intel compilers and aborts the startup with the error:

```
symbol lookup error: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libirng.so: undefined symbol: __intel_skx_avx512_memcpy
```

The only way I have to get MATLAB to work is to comment out the above variables in my .bashrc file, source it and start MATLAB.

This of course crazy and I was wondering if it was possible to actually have, for example, a .desktop files that ignores .bashrc or if there's any other way to have those environmental variables up and running, but have a software ignoring them.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd put the statements into a separate file and source it only when needed for development.

Comment: ... and only in the terminal window(s) where you intend to use the compilers, while the standard .bashrc will be used in other terminal windows.

Comment: +1 . . . or use the tools provided by your build system (such as placing them in a suitable `Makefile`) - the nearest you will be able to do otherwise I think is to reset the ENTIRE environment e.g. `Exec=env -i whatever`

Comment: What makes you think that "overriding system libraries might cause problems" is "crazy"? Anyways you can override the system variables again in a desktop icon if that's what you would like to do.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto what I think is crazy is to constantly have to edit my bashrc file whenever I have to switch to MATLAB, not overriding system libraries. In fact, if you could explain how to do it in a desktop file that would be great!

Comment: @PerlDuck how should that file be structured?

Comment: @Mutewinter you don't have to "constantly edit your Bashrc file", you just need to avoid overriding fundamental variables with incompatible ones. Then if you need a terminal session with custom stuff you can load it on demand. But if you want to follow the wrong approach, edit the `Exec` line in the launcher with a script that overrides the things back to what they were originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible to start `bash` with ignoring the `~/.bashrc` file. Specifically, via `--no-rc` flag:

```
 bash --noprofile --norc
```

You can make a wrapper `.desktop` file for that in a fairly simple way:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=No-rc shell
Comment=Starts Bash with --no-rc flag
Exec=bash --noprofile --norc
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/terminal.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Development;
```

---

Alternatively, you could modify the `~/.bashrc` in such way, that would allow you sourcing it dynamically. For instance, I'd personally do something like this:

```
if [ -z "$no_intell_compilers" ][ "$no_intell_compilers" = "false" ]; then
    source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018.2.046/bin/psxevars.sh
    export CC='/opt/intel/bin/icc'
    export CXX='/opt/intel/bin/icpc'
    export FC='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
    export F77='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
    export CFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
    export CXXFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
    export FCFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
fi
```

What this does is that it checks for environment variable `no_intell_compilers`; if it is unset or set to `false`, `~/.bashrc` will export those variables. When you want to start over without those variables in the environment, do

```
$ no_intell_compilers="true"
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Once you're done developing in that shell, just `unset no_intell_compilers` and source the file again to have the variables back.

Comment: Thanks! I actually modified your answer for the desktop file to launch Matlab directly. My Exec is Exec = bash --noprofile --norc  -c 'exec $PATHTOMATLAB/matlab' and it seems to be working fine!

Comment: @Mutewinter    Good use of `exec`  there !  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exactly answer your question about ignoring `.bashrc` but I figured this could be a reasonable alternative:

Remove the statements needed for development from your `~/.bashrc` and put them in a separate file instead, e.g. `~/dev-env`:

```
#
# Set environment for icc compiler
#
source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2018.2.046/bin/psxevars.sh
export CC='/opt/intel/bin/icc'
export CXX='/opt/intel/bin/icpc'
export FC='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
export F77='/opt/intel/bin/ifort'
export CFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export CXXFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
export FCFLAGS='-O3 -xHost -ip'
```

Then, when you want to develop something with the `icc` compiler, simply source that file manually in the affected terminal window(s):

```
source ~/dev-env
```

The file doesn't need to be executable because you won't *execute* it but *source* it instead. This means the statements therein are processed *by the current shell* and hence affect the current shell. If you would make it executable and then execute it, a subshell would be spawned, the settings were set there and then the subshell would close. Not what you want.